# Some Time's PM time value is coming as AM in momentjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, momentjs

Im using moment js for date functionality.

Old code is:

```
moment("2019/08/28 22:00", 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').format('h:mm A');
```

`O/P: 10 PM`. it's working fine. later I changed code is like below.

New code is:

```js
let scheduleDate = moment("2019-08-28");
let dateFormat = moment(scheduleDate).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
console.log(moment(dateFormat + " " + "22:00", 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm').format('h:mm A'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

`O/P: 10 AM`. but value is wrong.

above issue is coming as intermediate. Please help is there any wrong in new code.

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: both are working fine on my side, I'm using moment 2.18.1

Comment: works fine [here](https://jsbin.com/kihonocahe/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: It's  not efficient to unnecessarily re–parse and copy moment objects. Why wouldn't you do `moment('2019-08-28' + ' 22:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').format('h:mm A')`?